# Javascript setTimeout error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I'm having a weird problem where whenever I go to my website It runs perfectly, but if I try and go to that same website again it won't load. If i wait about 1-2 minutes and go to the website again it will work. 
I believe it has something to do with either my jquery or my javascript setTimeout loop but i can't figure out how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

here is my code

```
  <html>
   <head>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var question=1;
     function get(){

    $.post('ref.php', {num: question}, 
        function(output){
        $('#choice1').html(output).show();  
        }
    )
    $.post('ref2.php', {num: question}, 
        function(output){
        $('#choice2').html(output).show();  
        }
    )
    $.post('ref3.php', {num: question}, 
        function(output){
        $('#choice3').html(output).show();  
        }
    )
    $.post('ref4.php', {num: question}, 
        function(output){
        $('#choice4').html(output).show();  
        }
    )

    setTimeout('get()',1000);//THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE ERROR IS

    }


    </script>

    </head>

    </head>
    <body onload="get()" style="text-align:center; margin-top:20px; background-color:#000000">
    <p style="position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:110px;
    color:WHITE;
    font-size:30px;">Question Answer Grid</p>

    <p style="position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:200px;
    color:GREEN;
    font-size:24px;">Choice A:</p>

    <p id="choice1" style="position:absolute;
    left:140px;
    top:200px;
    color:GREEN;
    font-size:24px;"></p>

    <p style="position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:260px;
    color:BLUE;
    font-size:24px;">Choice B:</p>

    <p id="choice2" style="position:absolute;
    left:140px;
    top:260px;
    color:BLUE;
    font-size:24px;"></p>

    <p style="position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:320px;
    color:RED;
    font-size:24px;">Choice C:</p>

    <p id="choice3" style="position:absolute;
    left:140px;
    top:320px;
    color:RED;
    font-size:24px;"></p>

    <p style="position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:380px;
    color:YELLOW;
    font-size:24px;">Choice D:</p>


    <p id="choice4"style="position:absolute;
    left:140px;
    top:380px;
    color:YELLOW;
    font-size:24px;"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the php files:

```
  <?php
        $connect=mysql_connect("****","*****","*****");    
    mysql_select_db("*****");
    $num=$_POST['num'];
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE number='$num'");
    $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $query2['q1'];
    ?>
```

everything works except for that one error

Comment: Try to remove the single quetoes around get() function (Where the setTimeout is called)

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/pqdEK97KMmwqOEAwgsGm?p=preview

Comment: when your website dosen't load does it gives any kind of error in console?

Comment: @guleria is right: can you paste server output (maybe generated HTML structure and console output?) in case when website doesn't work? Every second you make 4 POST requests to the server - it shouldn't overload your server but everything's possible. Or maybe there's some error while fetching data from db? You don't have any error checking there.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
setTimeout('get()',1000)
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(get,1000)
```

`get` is a function. You don't need `'` and `()` here.

Comment: it is perfectly fine... as setTimeout() takes a string as an argument and executes it in the global scope